# Connect to database in same network with iOS

Tags: ios, database

Since this is a completely new topic for me, I'm asking for your help.
I'm looking for an approach to **retrieve data**(not adding or updating) from a local SQL **database** via IP address on **iOS**.

To specify the problem:
The app is supposed to check if new data is available (e.g. news). If new data is available the app retrieves the data from the database. The app only updates in a local network (same as the database)!

I have found several topics about databases, but they all use some kind of web service. If possible, I **don't want to implement a web service** to retrieve data.

What's the best approach? Can anyone provide an example?

Thank you for your time and help
Timm

Comment: What kind of database? Why do you want direct access to the database instead of accessing some sort of web service or other front end to the database?

Comment: oh sorry, i just overread this comment.
Actually I don't know yet. but since the files are .innodb and .mylsam , I guess its MYSQL.
So far, i can't have a webservice since its not my server where the database is running on. i just have the possibility to work app-sided with the ip and guest user i have for this database.

Comment: You need a MySQL client library that allows you to remotely connect to a MySQL database. One option might be http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cocoa-framework/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to create a web service through which you provide the data from the database.  By doing so, you increase your ability to make changes to this web service if your database connections, queries need to change, and in some cases, removing the need to redeploy a new iOS app every time a change occurs.

Also, by adding in the web service, you add a layer where you can implement some security so that those that should not be accessing this data, don't.  You can then keep your iOS app small and lightweight for installation, and only ship the data to the app after the application first launches.

Another big reason why you should **not** connect directly to the database from your iOS app is the fact that you would have to keep your database exposed to allow for any IP in your network to access it which is a no-no.  You should minimize the number of connections allowed to your database to keep it secure, this is easily accomplished by the use of a web service.

Comment: ty for your answer. but beside of these advantages, wow can I access the database without an webservice?

Comment: You are welcome.  You'll see over time that implementing the web service approach will always have benefits over directly accessing the database from the app.

Comment: But still :D
How can i access a DB when i ONLY got the IP address and username:pw and NO webservice?

Comment: I do not know how to connect to a database directly from an iOS app without the use of a web service, if it is even possible for that matter.  And to be honest, I really think you should stay away from doing so.  Your best bet is to create a web service and interface with your database via the web service.  If you do a simple google search for "ios connect to database" you will see that every instance describes the use of a web service to interface with the database.

Comment: @Timm You still didn't answer my comment below your question. What database are you talking about? MySQL? Oracle? What?

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. As we took this project further we accepted that we cant connect directly.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad that I was able to help you out.